# Time Series Visualization from Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, visualization

I have a **Cassandra** Database and a **Spark** cluster that will get his inputs from Cassandra to do some processing.

In my Cassandra database, I have some table that are **time series**. I am looking for a way to **visualize** those time series easily without multiplying databases.

**Grafana** is a great tool for that, but infortunately, it seems like there is no way to plug it to Cassandra.

So, for now I am using **Zeppelin** notebooks using my Cassandra/Spark cluster, but the available features to display time series aren't as good as those from Grafana.

I also cannot replace my Cassandra by InfluxDB, because my Cassandra is not used only for time series storing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no direct plugin for Cassandra as a datasource for Grafana. Below are the different possible ways you can achieve Cassandra to Grafana integration.

1. There is a pull request for Cassandra as a datasource https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/9774, this is not merged to Grafana master branch though.
   you could run a fork of Grafana with this PR and use the plugin.
2. You can use **KairosDB** on top of Cassandra (We can configure KairosDB to use Cassandra as a Datastore, so no multiple databases:) and use KairosDB plugin. but this approach has some drawbacks:

   - we need to map the Cassandra schema to KairosDB schema, KairosDB
     schema is metrics based schema.
   - Though KairosDB uses cassandra as
     a Datastore, it will store the data in different schema and table, so
     data is duplicated.
   - If your app is writing data to Cassandra
     directly, you need to write simple client to pull the latest data
     from cassandra and push to KairosDB
3. You can implement the **SimpleJSON** plugin for Grafana (https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource). There are lots examples available for SimpleJSON implementation, write one for Cassandra and opensource :)
4. You can push the data **ElasticSearch** and use it as a Datasource. ES is supported as a Datasource for all major visualization tools.

Comment: "Unfortunately there is no direct plugin for Cassandra as a datasource for Grafana"

Now there is such a plugin https://github.com/HadesArchitect/GrafanaCassandraDatasource

Answer (score 2):

A bit too late but there is a direct integration now, Cassandra datasource for Grafana

https://github.com/HadesArchitect/GrafanaCassandraDatasource

Comment: Is this plugin compatible with the latest version of Grafana i.e. Grafana 8.x ?

Comment: Since version 2.0.0 - yes. It's in the final stage, to be released this week.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use Banana Visualization, but for this Solr should be enabled on Timeseries Table. Banana is a forked version of KIBANA. Also has powerful dashboard configuration capabilities.

https://github.com/lucidworks/banana

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It look interesting, but it don't look like the project is really active anymore.
If I need to do a Database change, I am more inclined to go to an Elasticsearch and plug it to a Grafana or a Kibana